# read user permission from session or database

Tags: php, database, security, session, user-permissions

In my database, users have roles and each role has permissions. permissions have two fields permission group (such as users, posts, comments) and permission action (add 01, delete 02, edit 04, approve 08 which are bitwise).

For example, to add and approve a post:

```
permission[POST_PERMISSION_GROUP]= 01 | 08 ;
```

and I want to store it into session of user. But once admin changes permission of a user, session of that user should be updated. Now I'm in a dilemma if I should cache these permissions inside session or better to read them from database directly? each time user has access to each page several permissions have to be checked.

it would great if you share your experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can be done with permissions:

- Checking whether a certain user has a permission.
- Setting whether a certain user has a permission.

For this, you need two functions:

- `check_permission($user, $permission)`
- `set_permission($user, $permission, $allowed)`

A first implementation of these functions should manipulated the authoritative source for permissions (i.e. likely the database).

If you don't run into performance problems, leave it like that. If you have confirmed, that checking and settings perissions takes too long, then optimize, not earlier.

Comment: so which is the final choice, cache in session or direct read from database?

Comment: i have not implemented the website completely, so I should make final decision. you have just said leave it like that,

Comment: which way is more common among web developers?

Comment: With *leave it like that* I mean *stick with the first implementation*. I don't know what's more common, but best practice is to keep it simple and optimize only when necessary.